# How to get DCOMperm.exe from Microsoft

Tags: dcom

So I've been trying to solve the "The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission" problem and everything I've been reading says I need to get "DCOMperm.exe". There are plenty of links to usage and download links that point to non-MS sources. I'd like to get this direct from Microsoft, but I can't find it there.

Some people say that it's part of an SDK, but I'm not sure which one. Does anyone have any experience getting this exe?

Comment: Related reading on this source mirror: https://github.com/albertony/dcompermex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *source code* for `dcomperm.exe` is included with the [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279).

The project source directory is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\com\fundamentals\dcom\dcomperm
```

Comment: I was able to get the source file, install Visual Studio C# Express 2010 and import the .sln file into Visual Studios. I can't actually read anything since it throws an error that ".vcproj files are not readable by this version of Visual Studio".

Comment: Looks like the sample is C++ code. you have to also get Visual Studio C++ and it seems to build properly now.

Comment: @Doltknuckle The `.vcproj` file indicates the Project Type is Visual C++..  You would need the [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) to build this project.  I just installed VSC++ 2010 Express -- It updated the project files and compiled the `.exe` without errors.

Comment: Thanks @jscott, that seems to have done the trick. Unfortunately, fixing this causes even more errors to crop up. I think that has more to do with the program throwing the errors though.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for an application you're writing or for another application/component? If it's for another application/component then you can use dcomcfng to configure the permissions.

Answer (score -1):

you can download it from here , see at the end of the [page](http://www.myitforum.com/articles/11/view.asp?id=9323).

it is just that file, you don't need to download all the SDK if you need just that file.

Comment: >There are plenty of links to usage and download links that point to non-MS sources. I'd like to get this direct from Microsoft, but I can't find it there.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the compiled version here:

http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2012/11.aspx

Someone has kindly posted a genuine compiled version with batch files too.

Comment: The original poster said they're specifically looking for Microsoft links and that they've got non-MS sources aplenty.

Comment: I used Steven Van de Crean's executable (from the blog in the link), and it worked like the doctor ordered (even though it's not a MS-link). We had to replace a vendor's executable with that one in order to make their own product install successfully. Always trust the Dutch, I guess.